# No feasible entries for infix operator "+". How to understand datatype requirements/conversions?

Tags: types, vhdl

I am continuing having trouble/understanding with datatypes in VHDL. Does anyone have a good resource where I can learn more about this? Main issue I have is understanding what data type something is. For instance what is the data type when concatenating a '0' to a std_logic data type? Does it maintain being a std_logic or is it now a std_logic_vector? When looking up the "+" operator in the ieee numeric_std I see it takes 2 unsigned data types and should output a unsigned data type. Not sure what the best way is in converting one datatype to another. Does it depend on what package you are using? Am I suppose to do "unsigned('0' &  A)"??? I am getting really frustrated with these errors about wrong data types... Any help would be appreciated. I want to learn how to interpret data types and what a operator/functions wants/requires.:

```
 library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity FullAdd is port (
    A, B, Cin : in std_logic;
    Sum, Cout : out std_logic);

end FullAdd;

architecture arch_FullAdd of FullAdd is
signal input : unsigned(1 downto 0);
begin
    input <= ('0' &  A) + ('0' & B) + Cin;
    sum <= input(0);
    Cout <= input(1);
end architecture arch_FullAdd;
```

Comment: *Does anyone have a good resource where I can learn more about this?*  IEEE Std 1076-2008. "..what is the data type when concatenating a '0' to a std_logic data type? Does it maintain being a std_logic or is it now a std_logic_vector?"  9.2.5 Adding operators. That'd be `unsigned'('0' & A)` a qualified expression (9.3.5) while there's also package std_logic_unsigned instead of numeric_std treating std_logic_vector as unsigned in -2008. `'0' & A` is ambiguous with use clauses for packages std_logic_1164  numeric_std both  making `&` available (12.5 the Context of overload resolution).

Comment: Omar, at the risk of upsetting some people: if you need to learn *some* HDL language I would advise you to start with System Verilog. You have less strong typing. Many advantages which VHDL in the past was offering above Verilog have been included now. Also, what I see, System Verilog is advancing faster then VHDL in adapting new languages constructs.